# Use a Global ArrayCollection in Flash Builder Mobile application?

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder, arraycollection

I am currently developing a mobile application using the latest version of Flash Builder and I need to create a Global ArrayCollection to store information in that is pulled from a local DB. I can pull back the data from the DB fine however I cannot seem to access the Global variable when I try. I have the follng .as file called "Model.as" which is located in a folder called valueObjects and that file contains the following code:

```
package valueObjects
{
    import flash.data.SQLConnection;

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    public class Model
    {
        public var ids:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        public function Model()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to start populating this ArrayCollection with the info from the database so i import the class into the Default Package mxml doc which will be loaded up first when the app starts by using:

```
import valueObjects.Model;
```

Then in a private function I try to access the ids ArrayCollection and populate it however I get the following error:

```
-1120: Access of undefined property ids.
-Access of undefined property ids
```

Can anyone please help with this?? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or easiest way is make array static.

```
public static var ids:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
```

but for this case is Singleton way better.

Answer (score 2):

Have you created an instance of your Model class?

In the classes you want to access it, you should do something like this:

```
var myModel : Model = new Model();
```

To share the model instance between classes, you're going to have to do slightly more work.  Either by passing around a reference to the same object, or using an alternate method such as creating a Singleton.  Many Flex frameworks, such as Cairngorm or RobotLegs, use Singletons if you need an example.

Comment: Hi,

Yes I have this which creates an instance of the model:

protected var model:Model = new Model();